# How to open Password protected Excel file in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: microsoft-office

Previously I was using dual boot (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04). At that time I created some Excel files with password protection. Now I am using only Ubuntu 12.04 and not Windows. iI want to open those files in Ubuntu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

LibreOffice supports this feature out-of-the-box.

Details can be found [here](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/About_Converting_Microsoft_Office_Documents#Opening_Microsoft_Office_Documents_That_Are_Protected_With_a_Password).